# passing all members of a json array from an API call in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, sdwebimage

Hi have a project which I implemented ImageSlideshow and sdwebimage. Images are gotten from an API call but in the docs of ImageSlideshow SDwebImages are implemented as below

```
let sdWebImageSource = [SDWebImageSource(urlString: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432679963831-2dab49187847?w=1080")!, SDWebImageSource(urlString: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1447746249824-4be4e1b76d66?w=1080")!, SDWebImageSource(urlString: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1463595373836-6e0b0a8ee322?w=1080")!]
```

which works well but for my own project I have all the images in an array and I want to display this images in the ImageSlideshow. I do not know the number of images so it is difficult to hard code it so how can I pass the array of images. `ProductServices.instance.selectedProduct?.productImg[0])` this gives me the image at the first index. the images could be up to the fifth index. how can I pass this?

Comment: **productImg[0]** is image url string and you want to fill the array like the above  sample ?

Comment: yes with `productImg[0]` `productImg[1]` `productImg[2]` .... I do not know the number that may be contained in the array and if it is empty I want to display a custom image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
var allImages = [SDWebImageSource]()
if let allStr = ProductServices.instance.selectedProduct?.productImg {
    for str in allStr {
       allImages.append(SDWebImageSource(urlString:str))  
   }
}

if allImages.isEmpty {
   // display custom image // or add it's default str 
}
```

Comment: `if allImages.isEmpty {
            // display custom image // or add it's default str
            slideshow.setImageInputs(localImg)
        } else {
            slideshow.setImageInputs(allImages)
        }` this crashed the app when I click on a cell with empty image

Comment: `    let localImg = [ImageSource(imageString: "image_not_found")!]
`

Comment: **localImg** is the reason of the crash as you supply invalid url for the default image , i don't know your UI but you can put default image and manage it's visibility according whether there are images or not or instead supply a valid url for the default image

Comment: I got the problem. It was because I forced unwrap it. Thank you so much